# Where can I find the Royal Society report on the controversy over the invention of differential calculus?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, newton, leibniz

Where can I find the report on the [Leibniz–Newton calculus controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy) mentioned in [this](https://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic3/3b/3b_4history_2.html) article?

> In 1712 the Royal Society in England wrote a report purporting to settle the matter — except, the whole investigation was effectively directed by Newton himself. The report found that Leibniz had concealed his knowledge of Newton's work — based on facts now known to be false.

I have found numerous places online where it is discussed, but not the actual text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At request of Leibniz himself, the *Royal Society* appointed a commission which had the task of dealing with a dispute that followed an article by John Keill published in 1710 in *"Philosophical
Transactions of the Royal Society"*, about centripetal forces, in which the author not only claimed the priority of Newton in the discovery of calculus, but also accused Leibniz of plagiarism.

In 1712 the commission published the *Commercium epistolicum*, which gathered  documents about the controversy and the report of the Royal Society, in which Keill's statements were judged valid. $^1$

**There are several editions of the *Commercium***.

**A 1856 edition** is:

*Commercium epistolicum D.J. Collins et aliorum de Analiysi promota:* Jussu Societatis Regiae in lucem editum: et iam cum eisudem recensione praemissa, et iudicio primari, ut ferebatur, Matematici subiuncto, iterum impresum. *Ou correspondance de J.Cloons et d'autres savants célèbres du XVII siècle, relative à l'Analyse supérieure*, reémprimée sur l'édition original de 1712, avec l'indication des variantes de l'édition de 1722, complétée  par une collection de pièces justificatives et de documents, et publiée par J. B. Biot et F. Lefort. Mallet et Bachelier, Paris, 1856.

In this edition the Report of The Royal Society in on page 182.$^2$

You can see it, for instance, here:

https://www.amazon.it/Commercium-Epistolicum-Collins-Aliorum-Analysi/dp/1247589145.

**Other editions** can be seen here (the 1722 edition):

https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/1215929

or here:

https://www.martayanlan.com/pages/books/3615/isaac-newton-john-collins/commercium-epistolicum-de-analysi-promota?soldItem=true.

**Another edition of the  *Commercium* is included  in Newton, I., *Opera quae extant omnia*,** Nichols, London 1782.

You can see here:

https://www.rct.uk/collection/1090227/isaaci-newtoni-opera-quae-exstant-omnia-v-1-sir-isaac-newton

or here:

https://www.amazon.it/Isaaci-Newtoni-Opera-Exstant-Omnia/dp/0461972328.

**An Italian translation** of the Report of the Royal Society, based on 1856 edition,  is in Cantelli, G., (ed.), *La disputa Leibniz-Newton sull'analisi* , mentioned in the footnotes, p. 151.

---

$^1$  <sup>See Cantelli, G. (ed.), Giusti, E. (intr.), La disputa Leibniz-Newton sull'analisi, Bollati Borighieri, 2006.</sup>

$^2$  <sup>Cantelli, cit. p. XXXV.</sup>